# jQuery FullCalendar Not Available!

Tags: jquery, calendar

Anyone know of another place I can get a recent version of FullCalendar for jQuery?  The developer's site is down and can't find the download anywhere!  Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**[Github link](https://github.com/arshaw/fullcalendar)**

Surprised the site is down, thats a pretty popular calendar plugin for JQuery, maybe the author is just moving hosts. Anyway the above link looks to be a link to the most recent version updated March 19th of 2011.